# Regex matching multiple field value in a single line

Tags: c#, regex

i wish to match a multiple field value delimited by a colon in a single line, but each field and value text contains space
e.g.

```
field1   :    value1a  value1b

answer
match1: Group1=field1, Group2=value1a value1b
```

or

```
field1   :    value1a  value1b   field2   : value2a value2b

answer
match1: Group1=field1, Group2=value1a value1b
match2: Group1=field2, Group2=value2a value2b
```

the best i can do right now is (\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)");
Match m = regex.Match("field1   :    value1a  value1b   field2   : value2a value2b");
while (m.Success)
{
   string f = m.Groups[1].Value.Trim();
   string v = m.Group2[2].Value.Trim();
}
```

i guess look ahead may help, but i don't know how to make it
thank you

Comment: If you want the `Group1`, `Group2`, etc., labels, you'll have to generate them from your programming language.  Regex alone can't do that.

Comment: it is just a illustration, i edited the question to show the sample code also. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
(\w+)\s*:\s*((?:(?!\s*\w+\s*:).)*)
```

- `(\w+)` group 1, any consecutive words
- `\s*:\s*` a colon with any space around
- `(...)` group 2
- `(?:...)*` a non capture group, repeats any times
- `(?!\s*\w+\s*:).` negative lookahead with a character ahead, the following character must not form a word surrounds by any space followed by a colon. Thus the group 2 never consumes any words before a colon

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/NfmW4J/1/)

Comment: thank you, it works. but i don't quite understand what is the final dot used for after the negative look ahead.

Comment: The dot just matches any character, but before it matches, a negative lookahead checkes if it's a part of the word before a colon. If it is, the whole match ends at that point. This lookahead checks every time when the dot matches a character.

Comment: It works for uncertain number of values. If the number of values is fixed to 2. A simple [`(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+\s+\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/XUGlnS/1/) would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex based on a lazy  dot:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"(\w+)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\w+\s*:|$)");
```

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/Yw3CGr) and the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cw%2B%29%5Cs*%3A%5Cs*%28.*%3F%29%28%3F%3D%5Cs*%5Cw%2B%5Cs*%3A%7C%24%29&i=field1%20%20%20%3A%20%20%20%20value1a%20%20value1b%20%20%20field2%20%20%20%3A%20value2a%20value2b) (please mind that regex101.com does not support .NET regex flavor).

As you see, no need using a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat). The regex means:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: any one or more letters/digits/underscore
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with zero or more whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than a newline, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\w+\s*:|$)` - up to the first occurrence of one or more word chars enclosed with zero or more whitesapces or end of string.

Full C# demo:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "field1   :    value1a  value1b   field2   : value2a value2b";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"(\w+)\s*:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\w+\s*:|$)");
        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-- MATCH FOUND --\nKey: {0}, Value: {1}", 
                m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-- MATCH FOUND --
Key: field1, Value: value1a  value1b
-- MATCH FOUND --
Key: field2, Value: value2a value2b
```